# jQuery Replace 1st Instance of text

Tags: jquery

If I have text like this;

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>this is the real text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>more</p>
```

What I need is a piece of jQuery that will replace the first instance only of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` with ''.

So the result after the call should be;

```
<p>this is the real text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>more</p>
```

But if the first line is not `<p>&nbsp;</p>` then the call should do nothing.

**EDIT**

I've tried implementing the solution from @Joey C. but I can't get it to work.  The remove just doesn't.

```
var myHtml = "<p>abc</p><p>next para</p>";
var newElement = $(myHtml);

if ($(newElement).first("p").text() == "abc") {
    $(newElement).first("p").remove();
}

alert($(myHtml).text());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following finds the first instance of a p element and removes it from the DOM if it's html is equal to "`&nbsp;`" like you specified.

```
   if ($("p:first").html() == "&nbsp;")  
     $("p:first").remove();
```

If the html is stored as a string in a variable, myHTML, you could create a DOM element and perform a similar comparison. In testing, I discovered that it works better if you wrap the elements you are creating with a div:

```
  var myHtml = "<p>abc</p><p>next para</p>";
  var newElement = $("<div>" + myHtml + "</div>");

  if (newElement).find("p:first").text() == "abc") {
     newElement.find("p:first").remove();
  }

  alert(newElement.html());
```

This will not actually update the string containing the original html code, so you must reassign it as well if you still need it in that variable.

```
  myHTML = newElement.html();
```

Comment: what if the html is within a variable called say myHTML?

Comment: the html to check for within the p element?

just compare to the variable instead:
if ($("p:first").html() == myHTML)

Comment: No sorry, what if the html im searching in, not searching for, is inside a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I *love* jQuery (and functional programming in general) but sometimes native JavaScript is the way to go:

```
function ProcessParagraphs(elem)
{
    var children = elem.getElementsByTagName('p'); 

    if(children.length < 1)
        return;

    var p = children[0];

    if($(p).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length != 0) //remove *all* whitespace and see if anything is left.
     return;
    else
      elem.removeChild(p); 

}
```

If you have list of elements to process then I'd give them a class, say 'foo', and process them with jQuery

```
$('.foo').each(ProcessParagraphs);
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` doesn't have a leading capital.

Comment: also, you declare `children` as a variable and then redeclare when you are comparing it.